# Can I change the background colour of all my plots in Quarto by specifying a global option in YAML?

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, quarto

I would like to all my plots to have a black background.

The line of code below works well in r and every plot that I make has a black background however for this to work in Quarto I had to add this line in every code chunk that outputs a plot. I was wondering if there is an efficient way of working it around.

```r
par(col.axis = 'white',col.lab = 'white',col.main = 'white',col.sub = 'white',
    fg = 'white',bg = 'black', lwd = 2)
```

[image: sample image]
Something like that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{thematic}` in Quarto:

````r
---
title: "thematic"
format: html
---

```{r}
#| label: setup
#| echo: false
library(thematic)
thematic_rmd(bg = "black", fg = "white")
```

```{r}
#| label: plot_1
plot(x = 1:100, y = runif(100))
```

```{r}
#| label: plot_2
hist(rnorm(100))
```
````

Renders to something like this:
[[image: Quarto HTML render1]

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect usecase of [`knitr chunk hooks`](https://yihui.org/knitr/hooks/#chunk-hooks) which can be used to call certain r codes before each code chunk if hook-option is set to be non-null.

> Chunk hooks are functions to be called before or after a code chunk when the chunk option is not NULL (it basically means as long as you set an option, the hook will be run)

So I have defined a hook function named `black_bg` that will run the par configs before each code chunk if the chunk option `black_bg` is set to `true`.

````
---
title: "Black Background"
format: html
---

```{r}
#| label: setup
#| echo: false

knitr::knit_hooks$set(bg_black = function(before, options, envir) {
    if (before) {
      par(col.axis = 'white',col.lab = 'white',col.main = 'white',col.sub = 'white',
          fg = 'white',bg = 'black', lwd = 2)
    }
})

```


## Plot1

```{r}
#| label: plot_1
#| bg_black: true

plot(x = 1:100, y = runif(100))
```

## Plot2

```{r}
#| label: plot_2
#| bg_black: true

hist(rnorm(100))
```
````

---

[image: plots with black bg]